# Convert image to numpy array, save it into Excel and reverse the all

Tags: python, excel, image, numpy, type-conversion

I tried my best to solve this issue on my own and I think I've hit a roadblock as it stands so far. I'm new to Python and so far so good on a web scraping project I'm trying to complete. What I'm currently trying to accomplish is to take an image, convert it into **something readable by Pandas** like a text string, store that into a single Excel cell, and then later convert it back from the text into the image for a finished product in Excel.

I tried a few different methods like `base64` which works for conversions to and from the image, but exceeds my single Excel cell desire. I'm currently an venture where I can store the image as an NumPy array into the Pandas dataframe and write that to excel which seems to work as it retains the numbers and structure, but I'm having issues reimporting it back into NumPy (I'm pretty sure it's an issue of going from Integers to Strings and trying to go back without really knowing how).

The initial dtype image array upon conversion from image to array is `uint8`
The stored Excel text string of the array when brought back into NumPy is `U786`. I've tried reconverting the string in NumPy, but I can't figure out how to do it.

A few potential roadblocks:

1. The image is a screenshot from Selenium that I am saving from my web scraping
2. I'm writing all my scraped contents to include the image screenshot converted to an array from a Pandas dataframe to the Excel at one time.
3. I'm using Xlsxwriter as my Excel Writer to write the dataframe and would to continue doing so if possible.

Below is an example of the code I'm using for this project. I'm open to any and all potential approaches that would fix this issue.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import openpyxl as Workbook
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

#----Opens Image of interest, adds text, and appends to dataframe
MyDataTable = [] #Datatable to write to Excel
ExampleTextString = "Text for Example" #Only used as without it Pandas gives an error of not passing 2D array when saving to excel
MyDataTable.append(ExampleTextString)
img = Image.open('example.png') # uses PIL library to open image in memory
imgtoarray = np.array(img) # imgtoarray.shape: height x width x channel
MyDataTable.append(imgtoarray) #adds my array to dataframe

#----Check my array image with matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(imgtoarray)

#----Pandas & Excelwriter to Excel 
df = pd.DataFrame(MyDataTable)                 
df.to_excel('ExampleSpreadsheet.xlsx', engine="xlsxwriter", header=False, index=False)

#------Open Array Test Data and where NumPy Array is Saved-----
wb = Workbook.load_workbook(filename='ExampleSpreadsheet.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']
testarraytoimg = sheet_ranges['A2'].value
print (testarraytoimg)
```

Comment: Maybe revisit the idea of using Excel as a filesystem... what's wrong with a file? And what's the benefit of using Excel?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I’m not opposed to that idea. Currently I have all the other data in an Excel file and Excel will ultimately be the final product format for where it’s going. I think to me just made sense to try and keep it all in one type of format since that’s how I have everything else so far. I am open to a better way to store images as base64 strings to later reencode back into images to place back into Excel using something like Openpyxl or Xlsxwriter if a better way is known.

Comment: What's a *"single Excel desire"* please? Also, I don't understand the bit about `U786` - I have never heard of that format. How big are your images in width and height in pixels? Are they colour? I don't know Excel that well - is there a maximal size for a cell in bytes? What about using multiple cells - is there a maximal number of rows or columns?